# What triggers Blackberry "low memory" warnings?

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry

I've been developing a Blackberry Phonegap/Webworks application.  If I watch it throughout usage on an OS6 device, it'll start ~1mb of memory usage.  As I use the application, memory usage will slowly rise (assuming a lazy garbage collector), and then usually by the time it reaches around 32mb, it'll drop back down to < 1mb.

If I leave the application open overnight, I'll come back the next morning to a "Low Memory Warning" recommending that I close my app.  The weird part is, I'll look under Settings, and my app is only using ~1mb of memory, and the device has 200mb RAM free.  I can't imagine that the application slowly climbed up to 200mb of memory usage without the GC kicking in.

The application pings the server for files in the background, and responds to push notifications, but watching it over the period of an hour or two neither seems to raise memory significantly (aside from the slow climb up to ~32mb and than a GC down to < 1mb).

Is there something weird about BB memory management I'm missing.  The device consistently has ~200mb free RAM and I've never seen my app anywhere close to using that amount.  But if I leave it a few hours I'll come back to a "memory warning" but see it's usage around 1mb.  Driving me and a client up a wall.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common issue with the BB OS6. I have been having the same issue with my Webworks Blackberry build. The first time I begin using the app it is running fine but when I begin to process other pages on the app I receive a pop-up telling me that "the device memory is too low - please close the following items". Then the app icon changes to what looks like a generic folder. I can still use the app afterwards and it's not always consistent in terms of how long you can use the app for before you get the warning even though, like you, I find that memory usage is below the minimum

I did some research and it appears this is a persistent problem on the Blackberry OS 6. Deleting the app and reinstalling it does not help neither does restarting the app.

Take a look at this link to view deeper issues related to low device memory

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Device-memory-is-Low-issue-for-an-WebWork-app/td-p/1166441/page/16